# change the position of textfield inside an expandable uitableview cell in iOS

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Hi, I am new to iOS and i am trying to have two text fields inside a custom table view cell and the cells are dynamic, so I will be having two text fields in each cell and when a cell is selected the cell will expand

1. How can I reposition the text field when the cell expands? One text field should be on the top and the other one on the bottom inside the tableview cell.
2. How can i access the `uitext` field delegate inside `uitable` view delegate
   i.e.:

   ```
   textFieldShouldBeginEditing inside tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
   ```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having two different custom UITableViewCells - one for viewing and one for editing. When `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, replace the selected cell with the second custom cell designed for editing. When the user is finished, replace it again with the original custom cell type.

For your second question about accessing subviews of the UITableViewCell, you have several options. I'm going to assume you're using storyboards.

1. If you created a custom class for your UITableViewCells, you can add the UITextView as a class property and connect it as a outlet from your storyboard to your class by making it an IBOutlet. That way you can access it via `self.nameOfTextView`.
2. If you don't want to create a custom class for your UITableViewCells, you can assign the subviews tags and access them via `(UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]`. This second option can also be used if you aren't using storyboards.